# MongoDB Java - Fetching id in nested json

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

I have the following json structure. I am trying to retreive run the following mongo query in java where hData._id is not null.

```
MongoDb Query: db.Collection.find({},{"hData._id":1, "hData.createdBy":1} )

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55567e594e3256a23565ce58"),
       "hData" : {
        "isDeleted" : false,
        "canDelete" : false,
        "canUpdate" : false,
        "createdBy" : “xyz”,
        "createdDate" : "2015-05-15T15:05:30",
        "_id" : "7"
    },
    "changeDate" : "2015-02-19T16:02:12",

}
```

The code i have written in java to fetch the hData._id is

```
MongoCursor<Document> cur = col.find(new BasicDBObject("hData._id", new BasicDBObject("$ne",null)))).iterator();
        try{
            while(cur.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(cur.next().getObjectId("hData._id"));
                i++;
            }
        }finally {
            cur.close();
        }
```

However, hData._id is returned as `null`. Could you help me with this ?

Comment: Did you check what cur.next() is? I think you cannot call getObjectId("hData._id") on it.

Comment: which version of mongo driver are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get nested properties using dot notation, e.g. `x.y`.

So in your example you need to get `hData` first, then call get on the `_id`. Like this:

```
    MongoCursor<Document> cur = col.find(new BasicDBObject("hData._id", new BasicDBObject("$ne",null))).iterator();

    while(cur.hasNext()){
        System.out.println(cur.next().get("hData", Document.class).getString("_id"));
    }
```

Also note that in your example `hData._id` is shown as a String and not as an ObjectId, hence in my example I've used `getString()`.

**EDIT**
Since it sounds like you may have mixed types for `hData._id` here's a more robust example with type checking and some extra debug output to illustrate:

```
    MongoCursor<Document> cur = col.find(new BasicDBObject("hData._id", new BasicDBObject("$ne",null))).iterator();

    while(cur.hasNext()){
        Document doc = cur.next();
        System.out.println("Document _id" + doc.get("_id"));
        Document hdata = doc.get("hData", Document.class);
        Object id = hdata.get("_id");
        System.out.println("hData._id " + id);

        // check type if you need to
        if (id instanceof String) {
            System.out.println("hData._id is String: " + id);
        } else if (id instanceof ObjectId) {
            System.out.println("hData._id is ObjectId: " + id);
        } else {
            System.out.println("hData._id is of type " + id.getClass().getName());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi @helmy - I am still getting for certain rows - ObjectId can not be cast to java.lang.string

Comment: Looks like you've got mixed types in your data. Might want to keep your data consistent. Anyhow, I've added another example on how to check and handle different types for a value.

Comment: Thanks for the edit @helmy. Your solution helps fixing this issue. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Filters` and `Projections` helper methods.

```
  try (MongoCursor<Document> cur  = coll.find(Filters.ne("hData._id", null)).projection(Projections.include("hData._id", "hData.createdBy")).iterator()) {
         while(cur.hasNext()){
              Document doc = cur.next();
              Document hData = doc.get("hData", Document.class);
              String id = hData.getString("_id");
              String createdBy = hData.getString("createdBy");
        }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks @Veeram, How do i handle -ObjectId can not be cast to java.lang.string ?

Comment: Np. Are all id's object Id's ? if yes, then use  `ObjectId id = hData.getObjectId("_id")` or else fix the data first.